Java BigInteger alternative for Arbitrarily Large Integers with Summation method
(This post has a continuation A Java class for representing big integers with arbitrary number of digits and summation method - take II.)
Intro
Now I have this rather simplistic BigInteger that mimics the idea of java.math.BigInteger.
Code
com.github.coderodde.math.BigInteger.java:
package com.github.coderodde.math;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * This class represents a non-negative integer with arbitrary number of digits.
 * Instances of this class are immutable.
 *
 * @version 1.0.0 (Oct 30, 2024)
 * @since 1.0.0 (Oct 30, 2024)
 */
public final class BigInteger {

    /**
     * This inner static class holds a single digit. It implements a doubly-
     * linked list of such digits.
     */
    private static final class Digit {
        byte value;
        Digit next;
        Digit prev;
        
        Digit(final byte digit) {
            this.value = digit;
        }
    }
    
    public static final class BigIntegerException extends RuntimeException {
        
        public BigIntegerException(final String exceptionMessage) {
            super(exceptionMessage);
        }
    }
    
    private Digit loDigit;
    private Digit hiDigit;
    
    private BigInteger() {
        
    }
    
    public BigInteger(String integerString) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(integerString, "'integerString' is null.");
        integerString = integerString.trim();
        
        // Check that is not blank. If it is, throw.
        if (integerString.isEmpty()) {
            throw new BigIntegerException("Input integer string is blank.");
        }
        
        final char[] chars = integerString.toCharArray();
        final int lastCharacterIndex = chars.length - 1;
        
        Digit digit =
                new Digit(
                        convertDigitCharacterToDigit(
                                chars[lastCharacterIndex]));
        
        // Initialize the least significant digit:
        loDigit = digit;
        hiDigit  = digit;
        
        // Initialize all the other digits:
        for (int i = lastCharacterIndex - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            final Digit d = new Digit(convertDigitCharacterToDigit(chars[i]));
            hiDigit.next = d;
            d.prev = hiDigit;
            hiDigit = d;
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        
        for (Digit digit = hiDigit;
                   digit != null; 
                   digit = digit.prev) {
            
            sb.append(Byte.toString(digit.value));
        }
        
        return sb.toString();
    }
    
    /**
     * Compute the sum of this and {@code othr} integers and return it. Both
     * {@code this} and {@code othr} remain intact.
     * 
     * @param othr the other operand.
     * 
     * @return a new instance of {@code BigInteger}.
     */
    public BigInteger sum(final BigInteger othr) {
        
        Objects.requireNonNull(othr, "The argument BigInteger is null.");
        
        Digit resultHiDigit = null;
        Digit resultLoDigit = null;
        
        Digit thisDigitIterator = this.loDigit;
        Digit othrDigitIterator = othr.loDigit;
        
        boolean carryOn = false;
        
        while (thisDigitIterator != null && 
               othrDigitIterator != null) {
            
            final byte sum = 
                    (byte)(thisDigitIterator.value +
                           othrDigitIterator.value + (carryOn ? 1 : 0));
            
            if (sum > 9) {
                carryOn = true;
            } else {
                carryOn = false;
            }
            
            final Digit digit = new Digit((byte)(sum % 10));
            
            if (resultHiDigit == null) {
                // Initialize the least significant digit:
                resultHiDigit = digit;
                resultLoDigit = digit;
            } else {
                // Prepend a new digit to the built big integer:
                resultHiDigit.next = digit;
                digit.prev = resultHiDigit;
                resultHiDigit = digit;
            }
            
            // Advance both the iterators:
            thisDigitIterator = thisDigitIterator.next;
            othrDigitIterator = othrDigitIterator.next;
        }
        
        if (thisDigitIterator == null && 
            othrDigitIterator == null) {
            
            // Once here, all we need to do is to check the 'carryFlag':
            if (carryOn) {
                final Digit prefixDigit = new Digit((byte) 1);
                resultHiDigit.next = prefixDigit;
                prefixDigit.prev = resultHiDigit;
                resultHiDigit = prefixDigit;
            }
            
            final BigInteger result = new BigInteger();
            result.hiDigit = resultHiDigit;
            result.loDigit = resultLoDigit;
            return result;
        }
        
        // If this big integer is longer than othr, will iterate:
        while (thisDigitIterator != null) {
            
            final byte nextDigitValue = 
                    (byte)(thisDigitIterator.value +
                          (carryOn ? 1 : 0));
                
            carryOn = nextDigitValue > 9;
            
            final Digit digit = new Digit((byte)(nextDigitValue % 10));
            
            // Prepend digit:
            resultHiDigit.next = digit;
            digit.prev = resultHiDigit;
            resultHiDigit = digit;
            
            // Advance the iterator:
            thisDigitIterator = thisDigitIterator.next;
        }
        
        while (othrDigitIterator != null) {
            
            final byte nextDigitValue = 
                    (byte)(othrDigitIterator.value +
                          (carryOn ? 1 : 0));
                
            carryOn = nextDigitValue > 9;
            
            final Digit digit = new Digit((byte)(nextDigitValue % 10));
            
            // Prepend digit:
            resultHiDigit.next = digit;
            digit.prev = resultHiDigit;
            resultHiDigit = digit;
            
            // Advance the iterator:
            othrDigitIterator = othrDigitIterator.next;
        }
        
        if (carryOn) {
            // Deal with the possible carry flag:
            final Digit prefix = new Digit((byte) 1);
            resultHiDigit.next = prefix;
            prefix.prev = resultHiDigit;
            resultHiDigit = prefix;
        }
        
        // Set the data of the newly created big integer and return:
        final BigInteger result = new BigInteger();
        result.hiDigit = resultHiDigit;
        result.loDigit = resultLoDigit;
        return result;
    }
    
    /**
     * Converts the character representation of a digit to a byte.
     * 
     * @param digitCharacter the digit character representation to convert.
     * 
     * @return a byte value corresponding to {@code digitCharacter}.
     */
    private static byte convertDigitCharacterToDigit(
            final char digitCharacter) {
        
        checkDigitCharacter(digitCharacter);
        return (byte)(digitCharacter - '0');
    }
    
    /**
     * Checks that {@code digitCharacter} is with the valid range.
     * 
     * @param digitCharacter the digit character to check.
     */
    private static void checkDigitCharacter(final char digitCharacter) {
        if (digitCharacter < '0' || digitCharacter > '9') {
            final String exceptionMessage = 
                    String.format(
                            "Invalid digit character: %c, " + 
                            "must be at least '0' and at most '9'.", 
                            digitCharacter);
            
            throw new BigIntegerException(exceptionMessage);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        benchmark();
        
        System.out.println("REPL:");
        
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("?> ");
            final String line = scanner.nextLine();
            final String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
            
            final BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger(tokens[0]);
            final BigInteger b2 = new BigInteger(tokens[1]);
            
            System.out.println("=> " + b1.sum(b2));
        }
    }
    
    private static void benchmark() {
        final Random random = new Random(666L);
        final java.math.BigInteger jmbi1 = buildJavaBigInteger(random);
        final java.math.BigInteger jmbi2 = buildJavaBigInteger(random);
        
        final String bigIntString1 = jmbi1.toString();
        final String bigIntString2 = jmbi2.toString();
        
        final BigInteger bi1 = new BigInteger(bigIntString1);
        final BigInteger bi2 = new BigInteger(bigIntString2);
        
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        
        final java.math.BigInteger resultJavaBigInteger = jmbi1.add(jmbi2);
        
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        
        System.out.printf("Java BigInteger summation in %d nanoseconds.\n",
                          end - start);
        
        start = System.nanoTime();
        
        final BigInteger resultMyBigInteger = bi1.sum(bi2);
        
        end = System.nanoTime();
        
        System.out.printf("My BigInteger summation in %d nanoseconds.\n",
                          end - start);
        
        System.out.printf(
                "Summation agrees: %b.\n", 
                resultJavaBigInteger
                        .toString()
                        .equals(resultMyBigInteger.toString()));
    }
    
    private static java.math.BigInteger 
        buildJavaBigInteger(final Random random) {
        java.math.BigInteger bi = java.math.BigInteger.ONE;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            bi = bi.multiply(
                    java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(
                            random.nextLong(Long.MAX_VALUE / 4)));
        }
        
        return bi;
    }
}

com.github.coderodde.math.BigIntegerTest.java:
package com.github.coderodde.math;

import com.github.coderodde.math.BigInteger.BigIntegerException;
import java.util.Random;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public final class BigIntegerTest {
    
    private static final int BOUND = 1_000_000_000;
    
    @Test
    public void sumZeroAndZero() {
        assertEquals(
                "0", 
                new BigInteger("0").sum(new BigInteger("0")).toString());
    }
    
    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void throwsOnNullString() {
        new BigInteger(null);
    }
    
    @Test(expected = BigIntegerException.class)
    public void throwsOnBlankString() {
        new BigInteger("   ");
    }
    
    @Test(expected = BigIntegerException.class)
    public void throwsOnInvalidDigit1() {
        new BigInteger("12x4");
    }
    
    @Test(expected = BigIntegerException.class)
    public void throwsOnInvalidDigit2() {
        new BigInteger("12#4");
    }
    
    @Test
    public void bruteForceTest() {
        final Random random = new Random(13L);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            final int int1 = Math.abs(random.nextInt(BOUND));
            final int int2 = Math.abs(random.nextInt(BOUND));
            
            final String int1String = Integer.toString(int1);
            final String int2String = Integer.toString(int2);
            
            final BigInteger bigInteger1 = new BigInteger(int1String);
            final BigInteger bigInteger2 = new BigInteger(int2String);
            
            final BigInteger bigIntegerSum = bigInteger1.sum(bigInteger2);
            final int intSum = int1 + int2;
            
            final String intSumString = Integer.toString(intSum);
            
            assertEquals(intSumString, bigIntegerSum.toString());
        }
    }
}

Benchmark output
When running the benchmark in main, I get:
Java BigInteger summation in 28400 nanoseconds.
My BigInteger summation in 3372300 nanoseconds.
Summation agrees: true.
REPL:
?> 11 9
=> 20
?> 999999 1
=> 1000000
?> 

Critique request
I have two main concerns:

Can I improve my code,
Can I speed up the sum()?


Why don't you use Character.isDigit(char) and Character.digit(char, int)? An obvious speedup would be to split the number to nine digit segments instead of one digit segments. But you would still be 10 times slower than the benchmark.

@TorbenPutkonen Word. If I ever get to a follow-up question, I will definitely deploy your suggestions.

Unit Tests

@ParameterizedTest

When you have a use case with multiple input variations to be tested, you can create a parameterized test instead of writing multiple tests with different input values (like throwsOnInvalidDigit1(), throwsOnInvalidDigit2() in your code).
In JUnit 5 parameterized methods are annotated with @ParameterizedTest instead of @Test and accompanied by an annotation specifying the source of input parameters, such as @ValueSource, @MethodSource, @CsvSource, etc.
Raw JUnit:
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(strings = {" ", "12x4", "12#4"})
public void constructor_ShouldThrow_OnInvalidString(String input) {
    assertThrows(
        BigIntegerException.class,
        () -> new BigInteger(input)
    );
}

Assertion assertThrows(), as well as annotations @ParameterizedTest, @ValueSource are available only with JUnit 5 (the first major version release was in 2017). I see that you're still using JUnit 4 based on @Test(expected) (this annotation parameter was removed in version 4.13), but there's no excuse for utilizing obsolete tools in your small pet-projects
JUnit + AssertJ:
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(strings = {" ", "12x4", "12#4"})
public void constructor_ShouldThrow_OnInvalidString(String input) {
    assertThatThrownBy(() -> new BigInteger(input))
        .isInstanceOf(BigIntegerException.class);
}


Descriptive test names

Test method name bruteForceTest() communicates neither which part of the system is under test, no what is the expected outcome.
The names of local variables in this method also not very descriptive, they should communicate responsibilities, not types. And additional intermediate variables are making it more difficult to follow the logic of this simple test.
@Test
public void sum_ShouldReturnCorrectSum() {
    var random = new Random(13L);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        int int1 = random.nextInt(BOUND); // Math.abs() here was unnecessary, nextInt() returns a non-negative number
        int int2 = random.nextInt(BOUND);
        String expectedSum = String.valueOf(int1 + int2);
        
        var bigInt1 = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(int1));
        var bigInt2 = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(int2));
        String actualSum = bigInt1.sum(bigInt2).toString();
        
        assertEquals(expectedSum, actualSum);
    }
}

Benchmark
Meaning no offense, but I would not call this measurement a proper benchmark for the following reasons:

You have 2000 instances of java.math.BigInteger (one 1000 for each initial value) eligible for garbage collection before the test starts (i.e. GC can interfere with your measurements).

Trying to measure the execution time of a single method invocation that takes a fraction of millisecond to run is doomed failure, the numbers you got are not trustworthy. The overall running time is too short, and you're running "cold" code (unoptimized by JIT-compiler), these measurements don't reflect how these methods will perform in real applications (yes, they suggest that one operation is slower than the other, but the numbers itself are extremely inaccurate).


Only because the results differ by orders of magnitude, we can ascertain that BigInteger.add() is more performant.
Why? Because:

Allocating a single contiguous block of memory (an underlying array of JDK's BigInteger) is cheaper, than allocating several thousand of smaller chunks of memory (one for each node of your BigInteger).

Reading a contiguous block of memory is also a fast, cache-efficient operation. For that reason, working with initial data of two java.math.BigInteger instances to be summated is a cake in comparison with thousands of jumps over the Heap required to traverse the nodes of your custom-built BigInteger.


There's very little you can do to boost the performance of the sum() method without changing the structure of your type.
And by the way, why causing name-collision with java.math.BigInteger? It's always a good idea to avoid such things to ensure that IDE auto-imports the right type. For instance, you might have called BigInt instead.
